# Show that there is no increasing function $f: \aleph_1 \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: set-theory

Firstly, I am not sure what $\aleph_1$ is. In my textbook, $\aleph $ is an order isomorphism from the class of ordinal numbers(OR) to the class of infinite cardinals(IC). Therefore $\aleph_0 = \aleph(0)= \omega$. In this context, $\aleph_1$ is the next infinite cardinal, but I cannot derive any more information about $\aleph_1$. I think showing that there is no increasing function $f: \aleph_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is done by assuming that there is a increasing function $f$ and induce a contradiction, but I'm currently lost.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if such a function existed, there would be a rational between $f(\xi)$ and $f(\xi + 1)$ for each $\xi < \aleph_1$. Do you see how to finish the argument from here?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be defined by $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^-x}$. Then G is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ to (0,1). So we need to just consider functions $f$ from $\aleph_1$ to (0,1). As the hint suggests, there is a rational number $r(\xi)$ for every element $\xi$ of $\aleph_1$ such that $r(\xi)$ is between $f(\xi)$ and $f(\xi+1$). Express the $r(\xi)$ as decimals. For every ordinal $\xi$ in $\aleph_1$, let $j(\xi)$ denote the first integer $j$ such that $f(r(\xi))$ and $f(r(\xi)+1$) differ in the $j$th decimal place. There are $\aleph_1$ ordinals in $\aleph_1$, but there are only a countable number of possible $j$'s. Therefore there an integer $k$ such that there are $\aleph_1$ ordinals $\beta$ in $\aleph_1$ with $j(r(\beta))$ = $k$. Let $S$ be the set of these ordinals. Cut the first $k$ decimal places from the decimals of the elements of $S=S_1$. Then we have the same situation again, only now it is a map $r_1$ from $S_1$ into (0,1) that gives us an $\aleph_1$-sized set of ordinals $\xi$ with $j(f(\xi))=k_1 \gt k$. Repeat the process to get a set $S_2$ and map from $S_2$ to (0,1) and a $k_2$ greater than $k_1$. This gives us an infinite increasing sequence of integers $k,k_1, k_2...$. Such a sequence must diverge to infinity. This implies that there are ordinals $\xi$ and $\chi$ such that $r(\xi)$ and $r(\chi)$ have all their decimals the same. Hence $f(\xi)$ and $f(\chi)$ are the same, contradicting the assumption that $f$ is injective. I am not sure the fact that there is a rational between each $f(\xi)$ and $f(\xi+1)$ is needed in this proof.

Comment: If $r(\eta)$ is a rational number, how does $f(r(\eta))$ exist?